# Mac 10.4 Sync Files

Tags: svn, file, directory, synchronization

I am using Google code svn and have a repository setup. Inside the repository I am including TinyMCE and now I want to upgrade all the files in this folder.  The problem I am having is if I checkout locally and then download their new version and replace the folder it wipes out all my svn files.  So in effect removes it from version control.

I was wondering what is the best method to update those folders & files but keep the svn files intact?  I have been searching but can't seem to locate any simple method.

Comment: Your title seems almost completely unrelated to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to use the `ditto` command.

It's as simple as:

```
ditto /path/to/newFiles /path/to/your/workingCopy
```

Answer (score 0):

What you may want is to setup [svn:externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s03.html), or you may also want to take a look at something like [Piston](http://piston.rubyforge.org/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Something as simple as `tar` will not nuke the `.svn` directories. Or `rsync` (unless you ask it to), or `unzip`, or writing a simple shell script, or...